# Authenticated Calls

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, http

I am currently doing an authenticated data fetch on the server-side as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("...");
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Is it possible to do this using jQuery?

Comment: [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) supports authentication (username, password), but you can't specify a different proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place that in a static method marked with the `[WebMethod]` attribute and call it *from* jQuery - that is, instead of doing the call directly through the proxy, you still get client-side async but the call still goes through your server.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. This seems to be the simplest for the time-being.